# Google map latitude / longitude showing null in geometry - Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I'm using google places api javascript sdk , and want to save the result in my db using ROR - I'm wondering that four day earlier , it was saving the lat/lng successfully but now it's saving as null . Below is my explanation

I've this code in my javascript

```
places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
places.nearbySearch(request, callback);

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      clearMarkers();
//alert(JSON.stringify(results));

$.ajax({
  url: "/myurl",
  data:{
    'google_searched_locations': JSON.stringify(results)
  },
  dataType: "json",
  method: 'post',
  async : false,
  success: function(data){

  }
  });
}
```

In the callback function when i do `console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lng());` it shows me result as `74.30889000000002` while when i do

```
console.log(results[0]);
```

**Output**

```
geometry
  Object { location=L}
location

L       { lat=function(),  lng=function(),  toString=function(),  more...}
equals  function(a)
j       function(a)
lat     function()
lng     function()
toString function()
```

which clearly makes sense . But in console of firefox , ajax data parameter showing the data in the following form

```
[{"geometry":{"location":{}}]
```

I skipped the other parameters for clarity because all other things are present in the request . But you can see location is totally 
empty , Why ? and how can i send `results[0].geometry.location.lng()` values alongwith i.e within location object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It occurs since Nearby Search Requests returns `location` property of [`google.maps.LatLng type`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng) and in order to save it needs to be serialized explicitly, for that purpose the following function could be used:

> - `toString()` Converts to string representation.
> - `toUrlValue` Returns a string of the form "lat,lng" for this LatLng. We round the lat/lng values to 6 decimal places by default.

You could introduce a new property for storing location string representation for that purpose as demonstrated below:

```
var results = results.map(function(item){
         item.geometry.locationString = item.geometry.location.toString(); //string represenation of location property
         return item;   
});
```

**Example**

```js
function initialize() {
    var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665, 151.1956);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: pyrmont,
        zoom: 15,
        scrollwheel: false
    });

    // Specify location, radius and place types for your Places API search.
    var request = {
        location: pyrmont,
        radius: '500',
        types: ['store']
    };

    // Create the PlaceService and send the request.
    // Handle the callback with an anonymous function.
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {


           //serialize location to string 
           var results = results.map(function(item){
                item.geometry.locationString = item.geometry.location.toString();
                return item;   
           });

           document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(results, null, 2);
        }
    });
}

// Run the initialize function when the window has finished loading.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
   html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions(like e.g. `lat()` and `lng()` in this case ) may not be transported via JSON.

You must first parse `result` and create some custom values with the the desired values to be able to transport latitude and longitude via JSON

Comment: dear you explained the logic correctly but @vadim also gave the code alongwith the logic , that's why i'm marking that as answer but your's is also 100% correct